# Convert table's selected columns to rows in SQL server and keep the Column title as value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying t convert the following table to the detailed table for reporting:

Sample:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Item location</th><th>Item code</th><th>Item type</th><th>Item number</th><th>4/1/2020</th><th>4/2/2020</th><th>4/3/2020</th><th>4/4/2020</th><th>4/5/2020</th></tr><tr><td>Milk</td><td>Location 1</td><td>1024</td><td>Food-1</td><td>1</td><td> 1,548 </td><td> 1,561 </td><td> 6,584 </td><td> 1,344 </td><td> 1,485 </td></tr><tr><td>Bread</td><td>Location 2</td><td>1524</td><td>Food-2</td><td>2</td><td> -   </td><td> -   </td><td> -   </td><td> 1,524 </td><td> 1,597 </td></tr><tr><td>Toast</td><td>Location 2</td><td>1525</td><td>Food-3</td><td>4</td><td> 1,504 </td><td> 1,526 </td><td> 5,423 </td><td> 1,434 </td><td> 1,244 </td></tr><tr><td>WheatBread</td><td>Location 3</td><td>1600</td><td>Food-2</td><td>5</td><td> 1,587 </td><td> 1,547 </td><td> 1,545 </td><td> 8,896 </td><td> 1,236 </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

the final output will be like this:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Item location</th><th>Item code</th><th>Item type</th><th>Item number</th><th>Values</th><th>Date Posted</th></tr><tr><td>Milk</td><td>Location 1</td><td>1024</td><td>Food-1</td><td>1</td><td> 1,548 </td><td>4/1/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Bread</td><td>Location 2</td><td>1524</td><td>Food-2</td><td>2</td><td> -   </td><td>4/1/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Toast</td><td>Location 2</td><td>1525</td><td>Food-3</td><td>4</td><td> 1,504 </td><td>4/1/2020</td></tr><tr><td>WheatBread</td><td>Location 3</td><td>1600</td><td>Food-2</td><td>5</td><td> 1,587 </td><td>4/1/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Milk</td><td>Location 1</td><td>1024</td><td>Food-1</td><td>1</td><td> 1,561 </td><td>4/2/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Bread</td><td>Location 2</td><td>1524</td><td>Food-2</td><td>2</td><td> -   </td><td>4/2/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Toast</td><td>Location 2</td><td>1525</td><td>Food-3</td><td>4</td><td> 1,526 </td><td>4/2/2020</td></tr><tr><td>WheatBread</td><td>Location 3</td><td>1600</td><td>Food-2</td><td>5</td><td> 1,547 </td><td>4/2/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Milk</td><td>Location 1</td><td>1024</td><td>Food-1</td><td>1</td><td> 6,584 </td><td>4/3/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Bread</td><td>Location 2</td><td>1524</td><td>Food-2</td><td>2</td><td> -   </td><td>4/3/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Toast</td><td>Location 2</td><td>1525</td><td>Food-3</td><td>4</td><td> 5,423 </td><td>4/3/2020</td></tr><tr><td>WheatBread</td><td>Location 3</td><td>1600</td><td>Food-2</td><td>5</td><td> 1,545 </td><td>4/3/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Milk</td><td>Location 1</td><td>1024</td><td>Food-1</td><td>1</td><td> 1,344 </td><td>4/4/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Bread</td><td>Location 2</td><td>1524</td><td>Food-2</td><td>2</td><td> 1,524 </td><td>4/4/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Toast</td><td>Location 2</td><td>1525</td><td>Food-3</td><td>4</td><td> 1,434 </td><td>4/4/2020</td></tr><tr><td>WheatBread</td><td>Location 3</td><td>1600</td><td>Food-2</td><td>5</td><td> 8,896 </td><td>4/4/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Milk</td><td>Location 1</td><td>1024</td><td>Food-1</td><td>1</td><td> 1,485 </td><td>4/5/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Bread</td><td>Location 2</td><td>1524</td><td>Food-2</td><td>2</td><td> 1,597 </td><td>4/5/2020</td></tr><tr><td>Toast</td><td>Location 2</td><td>1525</td><td>Food-3</td><td>4</td><td> 1,244 </td><td>4/5/2020</td></tr><tr><td>WheatBread</td><td>Location 3</td><td>1600</td><td>Food-2</td><td>5</td><td> 1,236 </td><td>4/5/2020</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I have tried this already... but it doesn't work somewhere near the insert statement, I can create new table out of the input table... need help validating the code...

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @sqlText as nvarchar(max)

SET @StartDate = '2020-04-01'
SET @EndDate = '2020-04-06'
SET @CurrentDate = @StartDate

WHILE (@CurrentDate < @EndDate)
BEGIN

   SET @sqlText = N'SELECT      
    distinct 
        [Item Name],
        [Item location],
        [Item code],
        [Item type],
        [Item number],
        ['+(format(@CurrentDate, 'M/d/yyyy'))+'] as 'Qunatity',
        '+(format(@CurrentDate, 'M/d/yyyy'))+'  as [DatePosted]
    FROM [dbo].[BaseTable]';

    -- Insert into table ---> this where it's erroring

    INSERT INTO  [dbo].[FinalTable] ([Item Name],[Item location],[Item code],[Item type],[Item number],[Values],[Date Posted])
    EXEC sp_executesql (@sqlText)


    SET @CurrentDate = convert(varchar(30), dateadd(day,1, @CurrentDate), 101); /*increment current date*/
END
```

Comment: Start with `PRINT @sqlText` instead of the insert.

Comment: Have you tried putting your "INSERT INTO ..... " into your @sqlText variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate single query from your table definition:

```sql
  SELECT Query = 
  'SELECT
        [Item Name],
        [Item location],
        [Item code],
        [Item type],
        [Item number],
        RotatedValues.Value,
        RotatedValues.DatePosted
   FROM dbo.MySource
   CROSS APPLY ('
     + STRING_AGG('SELECT Value = ' + QUOTENAME(columns.name) + ', DatePosted = ''' + columns.name + '''', ' UNION ALL ') +
   ') AS RotatedValues'
  FROM sys.tables
  INNER JOIN sys.columns ON columns.object_id = tables.object_id
  WHERE tables.name = 'MySource'
  AND columns.name LIKE '[0-9]%'
```

It will generate:

```sql
SELECT [Item Name],
       [Item location],
       [Item code],
       [Item type],
       [Item number],
       RotatedValues.Value,
       RotatedValues.DatePosted
FROM dbo.MySource
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT Value      = [4/1/2020],
           DatePosted = '4/1/2020'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Value      = [4/2/2020],
           DatePosted = '4/2/2020'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Value      = [4/3/2020],
           DatePosted = '4/3/2020'
) AS RotatedValues
```